# Numpy: find mean coordinate of points along line

Tags: numpy, interpolation

I have a bunch of points in a 2D space which all reside on a line (polygon). How can I compute the mean coordinate of these points on the line?

I don't mean the centroid of the points in the 2D space (as @rth initially proposed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291112/4419816)), but the mean location of the points along the line on which they reside. So basically, I could transform the line to a 1D axis, compute the mean location in 1D, and transform the location of the mean back into the 2D space.

Maybe these are exactly the necessary steps, but I think (or hope) that there is a function in numpy/scipy which allows me to do this in one step.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: The approach you describe in the question is indeed probably the simplest way for solving this problem.

Here is an implementation that calculates the positions of vertices along the line in 1D, takes their mean, and finally calculates the corresponding 2D position with parametric interpolation,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev

vert = np.random.randn(1000, 2) # vertices definition here

# calculate the Euclidean distances between consecutive vertices
# equivalent to a for loop with
# dl[i] = ((vert[i+1, 0] - vert[i, 0])**2 + (vert[i+1,1] - vert[i,1])**2)**0.5
dl = (np.diff(vert, axis=0)**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5 

# pad with 0, so dl.shape[0] == vert.shape[0] for convenience
dl = np.insert(dl, 0, 0.0)
l = np.cumsum(dl) # 1D coordinates along the line
l_mean = np.mean(l) # mean in the line coordinates

# calculate the coordinate of l_mean in 2D space
# with parametric B-spline interpolation
tck, _ = splprep(x=vert.T,  u=l, k=3)
res = splev(l_mean, tck)
print(res)
```

**Edit2**: Assuming now that you have a high resolution set of points for your path `vert_full` and some approximate measurements `vert_1`, `vert_2`, etc, what you could do is the following.

- Project each points of  `vert_1`, etc. onto the exact path. Assuming that `vert_full` has much more datapoints than `vert_1`, we can simply look for the nearest neighbours of `vert_1` in `vert_full`:

  ```
  from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
  tr = cKDTree(vert_full)
  d, idx = tr.query(vert_1, k=1)
  vert_1_proj = vert_full[idx] # this gives the projected corrdinates onto vert_full
  # I have not actually run this, so it might require minor changes
  ```
- Use the above mean calculation with the new `vert_1_proj` vector.

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe add a comment to the two "dl =" lines? I guess I'll have figured out what they do by that time, but it will be helpful for others because these lines are not that straight-forward.

Comment: Meanwhile I've tried it out and it works pretty well. However, something's still missing (no wonder, though, since I've not mentioned it in the question): The points in the set do not fully specify the path, but I do have the coordinates of the path. How can I specify the path in full resolution? (I have many sets of points which all reside on the same path, and I'd like all means also to end up on this path, which currently is not the case, of course, because the paths defined by the sets of points all differ slightly from the real path because of lacking information).

Comment: thanks for the Edit, I'll try it out tomorrow. However I fear you might have misunderstood me. I'm not talking about approximate measurements. My points are all located on the exact path, but they only represent a subset of all points that make up the path. Now the path reconstructed from such a sub-set is of course not exactly the same as the original path, and thus the resulting mean point will be slightly displaced from the original path. The remaining challenge now is to end up with all mean points located exactly on the high-resolution path.

Comment: @flotzilla the solution above, should work still either way. Or you can adapt it, following this general idea, if needed.

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately didn't manage to get all mean points on the original path. Anyway, meanwhile I remembered the Shapely package and indeed found a very easy solution that gives me exactly what I want (I'll add it as a separate answer). Thanks a lot for your help, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I've found the answer to my question, although using Shapely instead of Numpy.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

# lists of points as (x,y) tuples
path_xy = [...]
points_xy = [...] # should be on or near path

path = LineString(path_xy)            # create path object
pts = [Point(p) for p in points_xy]   # create point objects
dist = [path.project(p) for p in pts] # distances along path
mean_dist = np.mean(dist)             # mean distance along path
mean = path.interpolate(mean_dist)    # mean point

mean_xy = (mean.x,mean.y)
```

This works perfectly!

*(That's is also why I have to accept it as the answer, though I highly appreciate @rth's help!)*

Comment: You are right, `shapely` module  is probably the simplest approach here.